# Which version / link please, of Maven should I use for JBOSS 4.1?

Tags: maven, jboss

Which version / link please, of Maven should I use for JBOSS 4.1?

Can you please provide the "Install New Software..." link if possible.

I used http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/archives/0.9.7.20090210120238/

But I am getting errors when Checking Out the Maven Project.

Importing Maven Projects has encounterd a problem.

An Internal error occurred during "Importing Maven Projects"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of maven has no correlation with the version of jboss that you use.

You are possibly asking for the version of m2eclipse - the eclipse plugin for maven. It depends on the version of Eclipse that you use.

You would want to install [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) on [Indigo](http://eclipse.org/indigo/), the latest version of Eclipse.  Update site is [here](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases). Earlier versions of m2eclipse are not expected to work with newer versions of Eclipse.